# mongoose update creates a new document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i need to update the document when i click on update button but instead its creating a new document

```
//mongoose app.js file
app.post("/update",function(req,res){
const updatePost=req.body.update_btn;
Post.updateOne(updatePost,function(err){
  if(!err){
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect("/post");
     }
   });
});
```

this is the button to update

```
<form  action="/update" method="post"> 
    <button class="btn edit_ico btn-sm" type="submit" name="update_btn" 
     value="<%=post.title%>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only send the title to the update endpoint. Mongoose needs the _id attribute to update the existing document. Perhaps you can include a hidden form field?